# ¿Por qué no puedo conectarme a mi servidor SQLEXPRESS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

Necesito conectarme a un servidor SQLEXPRESS de manera local, el problema es que me genera un error después de colocar mis credenciales y darle en conectar.

La conexión la hago desde la herramienta SQL Server Managment Studio y no me había pasado esto antes.

He copiado el mensaje de error, esto es lo que muestra:

```
TÍTULO: Conectar con el servidor
------------------------------

No se puede conectar a ISC\SQLEXPRESS.

------------------------------
INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL:

Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Para obtener ayuda, haga clic en: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

------------------------------
BOTONES:

Aceptar
------------------------------
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes comprobar es si el servicio de SQL Server está funcionando. Para ello debes ir a "Servicios" o bien "Services" si el SO está en inglés. Alli busca SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER). En la columna "Estado" debe estar "En ejecución"
En caso de que no lo esté, lo puedes iniciar (menú contextual, Iniciar.)

Si todo está correcto, deberías poder conectar en el PC local, dónde se ubica el SQL Server. Si allí pudes conectarte, pero el problema es al intentarlo desde otro PC de la red, deberemos comprobar que la conexión esté correcta, que los puertos estén abiertos, etc.